# How make tkinter combobox loop work in class using a list as defaut and 1 dictionary in dropdown menu?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, tkinter, drop-down-menu, combobox

I'm having a hard time trying to solve this.

I loop through list --> "self.houses" to build the comboboxes.

I use keys of a dictionary "self.heroes" as options to be chosen in dropdown options

And finally I need "self.houses" list as default display in comboboxes (replacing empty cells) before choosing options. First combobox 'DC',  second combobox 'Dark Horse', and last one  'Marvel'

My actual app gets a large list of lists and dictionaries to be matched and reintegrated in a table. My brain is melting, so please if someone can help.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root= tk.Tk()
root.minsize(550,450)
root.maxsize(560,460)
root.title('mymyAPP')

class My_Guess(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent


        #keys are the options to be choosen - ITS WORKING FINE
        self.heroes = {'wonder woman':'wonder woman', 'iron man': 'iron man',
                   'astroboy':'astroboy'} 

        # list self,houses is used to create comboboxes loop - ITS WORKING FINE
                    
        #HERE IS THE PROBLEM:
        # How 'default' strings from 'self.houses' in empty combobox loop before choose
        # one and only string in each combo
        self.houses = [ 'DC', 'Dark Horse', 'Marvel'] 
        

        self.select_house_hero()
   
    def select_house_hero(self):
        
        self.definitions = self.houses
        for index, definition in enumerate(self.definitions):

            self.match_hero_house = StringVar()

            self.my_match = Combobox(self, values=(list(self.heroes.keys())),
                                               justify="center", 
                                               textvariable=self.match_hero_house,
                                               state="readonly")

            self.my_match.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',
                               lambda event, 
                               cmb=self.my_match: self.get_results_from_ComboBox(event, cmb))

            self.my_match.grid(row=( 1 + index),  column=0, stick='w')
            
            
    def get_results_from_ComboBox(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = My_Guess(root) 
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is an improved version of your code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class MyGuess(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.heroes = ['Wonder Woman', 'Iron Man', 'Astroboy']

        self.houses = ['DC', 'Dark Horse', 'Marvel']
        self.variables = []

        self.select_house_hero()

    def select_house_hero(self):
        for index, definition in enumerate(self.houses):

            match_hero_house = tk.StringVar(value=definition)
            self.variables.append(match_hero_house)

            my_match = ttk.Combobox(self, values=self.heroes,
                                    justify="center",
                                    textvariable=match_hero_house,
                                    state="readonly")

            my_match.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',
                          lambda event,
                          cmb=my_match: self.get_results_from_combobox(event, cmb))

            my_match.grid(row=index + 1, column=0, stick='w')

    def get_results_from_combobox(self, event, cmb):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.minsize(550, 450)
    root.maxsize(560, 460)
    root.title('My App')

    app = MyGuess(root)
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    root.mainloop()
```

First of move all that is outside definitions in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` because otherwise you will create another instance of `Tk` when importing the file.

Then also remove all your `*` imports, either import what you need or import the whole module as here (here it also uses an alias).

You also seemingly have no reason to have `self.heroes` as a dictionary so I changed it to a list.

The important part is that you need to save a reference to all the `StringVar`s otherwise they will get garbage collected, so I created an attribute `variables` that is a list that will be used in `select_house_hero` to append variables to. In the `self_house_hero` you don't need to create new instance variables, let them all be local because they will anyways have only the last value. Also set the value of `StringVar` to what you want to be displayed as the "title" of the Combobox.

Also PEP 8 suggests that class names are `CapitalCase` (and not `Capital_Snake_Case` or whatever that would be called)

Comment: Initially I was confused about how self.variables was influencing the loop results because I thought that it was appending ['DC', 'Dark Horse', 'Marvel'] but then I understood--> what the code append is each StringVar created in each iteration. So they are not erased. UAU!  Many thanks.